# Error when making generic expression dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, lambda, entity-framework-6

Based on [Generic expression abstraction issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450933/generic-expression-abstraction-issue) I want to make a more generic method to use "UpdateGraph" using Entity Framework 6.

Currently, I can call `SetOwnedCollectionMapping(t => t.ClassProperty)`, but I want to make a more reusable method by using the class instance and any class property.

Here is an example that I use :

```
private static void AddOrUpdate<T>(TDataEntity class1, T NavigationProperty) where T : class
{
    PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(TDataEntity).GetProperty("PropertyName");
    object value = pinfo.GetValue(class1, null);

    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(value.GetType(), "L");

    var arg = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(TDataEntity));
    var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, "PropertyName");

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body);
    SetOwnedCollectionMapping(lambda);

    using (var db = new ConsoleContext())//
    {
        db.UpdateGraph(class1, graphMapping);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

protected static Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<TDataEntity>, object>> graphMapping { get; set; }

protected void SetOwnedCollectionMapping<T>(Expression<Func<TDataEntity, ICollection<T>>> mapping)
{
    Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<TDataEntity>, object>> template = 
        _ => _.OwnedCollection(mapping);

    var map = Expression.Parameter(
        typeof(IUpdateConfiguration<TDataEntity>),
        "map");

    graphMapping = Expression.Lambda<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<TDataEntity>, object>>(
        Expression.Call(
            ((MethodCallExpression)template.Body).Method,
            map,
            Expression.Quote(mapping)),
        map);
}
```

The error I have is on the call method `SetOwnedCollectionMapping(lambda);`

> Error 1   The type arguments for method
>   'ConsoleApplication1.Program.SetOwnedCollectionMapping(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

I have doubt about my lambda expression. Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at `AddOrUpdate` you need to update following line to make compiler know what type are you going to pass there

```
SetOwnedCollectionMapping<T>(lambda);
```